# Not able to access index on local LAMP server on Linux Mint

Tags: php, zend-framework, apache2

I'm starting to play with Zend FrameWork, but I have had troubles with it. I try the follow the super guide [From Zero To Zend Framework in 10 minutes](http://www.jeremykendall.net/2010/04/17/from-zero-to-zend-framework-project-in-10-minutes/), but it amounted to nothing.

I also was getting that annyoing message

`apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName` twice.

And while I managed to fix [that](http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.com/2012/07/solved-apache2-could-not-reliably.html), this is how my local server looks like. [image].

This is how my `/etc/hosts` looks like.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   prueba.local
127.0.1.1   dradis

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And, according to [1](http://www.jeremykendall.net/2010/04/17/from-zero-to-zend-framework-project-in-10-minutes/), how my vhost configuration should be. This is in `/sites-avaliable` but symlinked to `/sites-enabled`.

`prueba.local` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName prueba.local
    DocumentRoot /home/seba/solartekka/test/prueba/public
</VirtualHost>
```

`/home/seba/solartekka/test/prueba` is where I have my project.

I have completed two days fighting with this, and my spirit is shattered. Does anyone have an idea of what may be happening?

I tried to give as much relevant information as I thoguht, but should you require more, I would happily deliver it.

Thanks!

Comment: At times, I have run into permission problems. As a test, try setting `chmod 0777 public/index.php`. Also, you could try browsing directly to `http://prueba.local/index.php`.

Comment: That was it! The index.php! Weid. Thank you, unfortunately I can accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer. ;-) Keep your spirit up. ZF can sometimes feel like a steep climb, but it's a great framework - ZF2 is even better - from which I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At times, I have run into permission problems. As a test, try setting `chmod 0777 public/index.php`.

Also, you could try browsing directly to `http://prueba.local/index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into apache logs messages file, they will give you a hint:

```
tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Frequent problem is missing Zend libraries.

Try to add this code to your vhost file:

```
<Directory "/home/seba/solartekka/test/prueba/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all 
        Order allow,deny
        Allow From all
</Directory>
```

Do not forget to restart apache.

Comment: Vhost file udpated. Apache restarted. No changes.
This appears in error.log:

  `[Tue Feb 05 20:48:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Attempt to serve directory: /home/seba/solartekka/test/prueba/public/`

Repeated at least 4 times.

Comment: Look at: http://serverfault.com/questions/388378/what-attempt-to-serve-directory-error-means-in-apache-log

Comment: "/home/seba/solartekka/test/prueba/public is where I have my project." - Your project should be in /home/seba/solartekka/test/prueba/ and index.php in /home/seba/solartekka/test/prueba/public regarding to vhost content.

Comment: Yes, I didn't express myself correctly. That's is correct.